# php get all div's content which class is X

Tags: php, class, domdocument

I am trying to get div content with php which div's class is **item ajax-product-load**. My code is:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// returns a list of all links with rel=nofollow
$nlist = $xpath->query("//div[@class='item ajax-product-load']");
print_r($nlist);
```

It return's me how many divs avaiable with class **item ajax-product-load**. But I need to get div's content. The result of this code:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 17
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$xpath->query(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [`DOMNodelist`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object. You need to retrieve an item with [`$item = $nlist->item(0);`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) and then get the content with [`$content = $item->textContent;`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent).

```
$nlist = $xpath->query("//div[@class='item ajax-product-load']");
$item = $nlist->item(0);
$content = $item->textContent;
print_r($content);
```